# methods of calculating cosine similarity between TF-IDF vectors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I'm calculating tf-idf vectors for content. I'm using the cosine similarity between vectors to find how similar the content is. I'm using the nltk library with sklearn and Snowball stemmer to create my tf-idf vectorizer, as shown below.

```
import nltk, string, os
from tfidf_functions import tokenize, stem_tokens,token_dict,stemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
import cPickle as pickle

token_dict = {}
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english") 
stopwords = ["the","and","I"]

def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer):
    stemmed = []
    for item in tokens:
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item))
    return stemmed

def tokenize(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    stems = stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer)
    return stems

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("path/to/trainingset"):
    for file in files:
        file_path = subdir + os.path.sep + file
        shakes = open(file_path, 'r')
        text = shakes.read()
        lowers = text.lower()
        no_punctuation = lowers.translate(None, string.punctuation)
        token_dict[file] = no_punctuation

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents='unicode',tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words=stopwords, max_df=1500)
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(token_dict.values())

with open('vectorizer.pkl', 'wb') as fin:
    pickle.dump(tfidf,fin)
```

I then open up vectorizer.pkl in a different file and use it to get feature vectors for new pieces of text and run cosine similarity on them. I've found two different ways of doing this but they have quite different results. **Why are my two methods returning different similarity values?**

```
def cosine_sim(text1, text2, vectorizer):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0,1]

def cosine_sim2(u,v):
    return np.dot(u,v) / (np.sqrt(np.dot(u,u)) * np.sqrt(np.dot(v,v)))

raw1 = "the quick brown fox jumped"

raw2 = "the lazy and quick dog jumped"

tfidf = pickle.load(open("vectorizer.pkl", "rb" ) )

response1 = tfidf.transform([raw1])
response2 = tfidf.transform([raw2])

#first function, pass the raw text and get vectors inside the function
print("similarity between above two items:"+str(cosine_sim(raw1,raw2, tfidf)))
#second fuction, pass the vectors calculated above 
print("similarity between above two items:"+str(cosine_sim2(response1.toarray()[0],response2.toarray()[0])))
```

It seems to me that both methods should arrive at basically the same response. The only difference I see is that the first method adds the text to the model since fit_transform is used instead of just transform. This doesn't explain the huge difference in output though - my training set is 5000 documents

Comment: Didn't go through all your code, but if you are using `sklearn` you could also try the `pairwise_distances` function. A quick read of the docs (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html) will tell you how to use it, pretty simple: `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric='cosine')`. It's just a quick way to obtain similarity values and maybe it helps you to get to know which approximation is right. Just leaving it here as a comment ;)

Comment: thanks! I'll check that out

Comment: the function you links calculates cosine distance which is a 1 - cosine similarity as far as I can tell. Its a bit hard to tell from the documentation but if I give it identical docs I get a 0

Comment: true that!  The measure I proposed is all about distance (2 identical docs are at distance 0) so it should be the complementary of what you are measuring

Comment: ah ok, nice to get confirmation. My second method gives the correct cosine similarity assuming the distance is correct. Cheers! Nice that your method directly accepts my scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix result variables

Comment: @alex9311 if you say the second function gives the right value, can you elaborate what is the issue with the first function. It will help me understand the difference better...Thanks

Comment: hi @Sid, honestly its been 4 years and I don't remember :)